# Spring Boot Redis Cache @CachePut is not updating the cache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

```
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "BooksCache", key = "#id")
    public Book findById(long id) {
        LOGGER.info("Fetching Book From DB For BookId: {}", id);
        return bookRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
```

Cacheable is working fine but when we add a new book or update the existing book cache is not updating

Here is the code for saveOrUpdate() and I have used @CachePut to update the cache but that was not working, Database is getting updated but cache is not updating

```
    @Transactional
    @CachePut(cacheNames = "BooksCache", key = "#book.id")
    public Book saveOrUpdateBook(Book book) {
        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }
```

I have tried @EnableTransactionManagement along with @Transactional Annotation.
I have also tried spring boot starter cache instead of redis cache,
But that was not working

Comment: i think the problem here is that the method is marked as private. If i remember right, the cache stuff is only possible on public methods.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I have tried with public as well but that was also not working, I have updated the question

Comment: do you call saveOrUpdate in the same class? I assume it, because it could be private?

Comment: Yes saveOrUpdate() is called in the same class in 2 methods addBook() and updateBook()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call @Cachable- methods from another class. Otherwise the cache proxy will not work and the cache doesn't change/trigger.

Comment: Yes @pL4Gu33 you are right, calling the methods annotated with cache annotations in same class will not work. 
I have changed the annotations to repository class and its working fine.

Thanks for the help